# How to add file upload and download feature to website?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, backend, file-sharing

I am working on a react website project with node backend where I need to have the following features:

1. Users with higher privilege can upload files.
2. All logged in users can view and download files
3. Files and folders should be displayed like in google drive (similar UI)

How to achieve this functionality. I don't want to use some kind of plugin to view google drive data. I want something robust, like with Amazon S3. I have searched a lot before writing this question but found nothing helpful.
should I work on this from scratch or are there some preferred libraries available?
Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use S3 with [Amplify](https://aws.amazon.com/amplify/). It makes working with AWS infrastructure, including S3, a bit easier.

Their docs include examples for [uploading files](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/upload/q/platform/js) and [downloading files](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/download/q/platform/js).

Amplify is modular, so you can use only the bits you need, but it works best when you buy into the whole AWS ecosystem (Cognito for authentication, S3 for storage, Lambda for API, etc.). Which might be a good or a bad thing, depending on your budget.

(By the way, not saying this is *the best* option – just *an* option)

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing your app using Node, you can use the AWS SDK for JavaScript to invoke AWS Services - including Amazon S3. You can perform [Amazon S3 operations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/s3-examples.html) using the Amazon S3 Javascript API. For example, to learn how to upload files to an Amazon S3 bucket, see:

[Uploading photos to Amazon S3 from a browser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/s3-example-photo-album.html)

The AWS SDK for JavaScript enables you to use [multiple AWS services](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/tutorials.html) in cooperation with each other to develop complex and sophisticated solutions. This section of the [AWS SDK for JavaScript Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/welcome.html) demonstrates several such solutions. By following some of the topics in this section, you will gain a deeper understanding of how to write app using the AWS JavaScript SDK.